# How to integrate multiple lock icons inside a chain made using CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I am having the following chain created in css. As you can see I have also created a padlock in svg. My goal is to add multiple of these locks directly to the chain:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.chain {
  position: absolute;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: #ff8e50;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8be5b), color-stop(35%, #fef1c9), color-stop(65%, #e69539), to(#f7f2a0));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, #f8be5b 0%, #fef1c9 35%, #e69539 65%, #f7f2a0 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( top, #f8be5b 0%, #fef1c9 35%, #e69539 65%, #f7f2a0 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, #f8be5b 0%, #fef1c9 35%, #e69539 65%, #f7f2a0 100%);
}

.link:nth-child(2n + 1):before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0.5rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.links.left .link {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.links.left .link:nth-child(2n),
.links.right .link:nth-child(2n) {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
  background: #ff8e50;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, from(#f8be5b), color-stop(35%, #fef1c9), color-stop(65%, #e69539), to(#f7f2a0));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( left, #f8be5b 0%, #fef1c9 35%, #e69539 65%, #f7f2a0 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( left, #f8be5b 0%, #fef1c9 35%, #e69539 65%, #f7f2a0 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #f8be5b 0%, #fef1c9 35%, #e69539 65%, #f7f2a0 100%);
}


/* Lock */

.shackle {
  stroke: #000;
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

svg {
  width: 100px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  &.unlock {
    .shackle {
      transform: translateY(-20%);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M64,234.667h384V512H64V234.667z"/>
<path class="shackle" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="60" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M362.666,436.5V128
 c0-58.901-47.766-106.667-106.666-106.667c-58.901,0-106.667,47.765-106.667,106.667v128"/>
</svg>

<div class="container">
  <div class="swag">
    <div class="chain">
      <div class="links left">
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please see below how my final result should look like:

[image]

The above display shows the lock added to every chain element.

Any suggestions how to do that?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: interesting, i will give it a try ;)

Comment: You might be using SCSS  I suppose, nesting CSS rules is not yet possible in pure CSS.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that you haven't already done?  You have the chain. You have locks on certain links.  I'm not understanding the distinction you're asking for.

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  Based on "The above display shows the lock added to every chain element. Any suggestions how to do that?", I thought he simply wanted to add the image to all the links.  See my new answer for a method to use the SVG directly without all the CSS

Comment: not working https://ibb.co/1MYHXFL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an idea without the use of `svg` and only with CSS *(I also simplified some of your code)*.

I used `radial/linear-gradient` in order to create the lock.

[image]

Simply insert the lock inside the link where you need to show it.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: 
    linear-gradient( to right, #f8be5b 0%, #fef1c9 35%, #e69539 65%, #f7f2a0 100%);
}

.link:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
  left: calc(50% - 1rem);
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.link:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  content: "";
  width: 2rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  top: calc(50% - 0.25rem);
  right: -1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, #f8be5b 0%, #fef1c9 35%, #e69539 65%, #f7f2a0 100%);
}

.lock {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:9;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: #000;
  top: calc(100% + 0.25rem);
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
}

.lock:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
    bottom: 97%;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
    margin-left: 0.25rem;
    background: 
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom, transparent 12%, #000 13%) 0 -37px/100% 200% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to right,transparent 77%,#000 0),
    linear-gradient(to right,#000 23%,transparent 0) 0px 19px/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="swag">
    <div class="chain">
      <div class="links left">
        <div class="link">
          <div class="lock"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link">
          <div class="lock"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          <div class="lock"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
          <div class="lock"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="link"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using complex CSS to create images seems overly gimmicky to me. Much more complex than practical, especially when SVG images are easy to reuse

Comment: I like your answers, but why does it not work for me? https://ibb.co/1MYHXFL

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE:  As mentioned in comments, using CSS vectors to draw images has a tendency to quickly over-complicate things; and this question is a good example.  If using SVG for both the chain links and the lock, this becomes pretty straightforward.  ("Complicated" beyond the simple fact that few drawing programs export to CSS "graphics".  It's more gimmick than everyday useful method.)

As-is, @Termani's answer works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48721640/339440

A more complete answer would involve swapping out the CSS chain links for an SVG (eg https://pixabay.com/en/chain-metal-chain-links-link-146909/ ), and then using `<symbol>` and `<use>` elements for the chain and locks.

Original answer:

Add a `<symbol>` tag with an id attribute within your SVG to mark the image you're re-using.  Then in your particular links you can add an `<svg>` tag with a `<use>` tag to reference the image.  (Code not tested, but should work)

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve">
    <symbol id="padlock" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <path d="M64,234.667h384V512H64V234.667z"/>
        <path class="shackle" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="60" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M362.666,436.5V128
    c0-58.901-47.766-106.667-106.666-106.667c-58.901,0-106.667,47.765-106.667,106.667v128"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
<div class="container">
  <div class="swag">
    <div class="chain">
      <div class="links left">
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"><svg><use xlink:href="#padlock"></use></svg></div>
        <div class="link"><svg><use xlink:href="#padlock"></use></svg></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"><svg><use xlink:href="#padlock"></use></svg></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
        <div class="link"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Code not tested, but should work` so test it and see that it's not working :) i know the svg are meant to be used to draw thing than CSS ... so  make this working with SVG ;) so we can compare the complexity. Then we will have two alternative and two different answer then the OP will pick the suitable one :) But in all the cases it's good to have both alternatives ;)

Comment: A good case study as to why CSS-as-image is often a bad idea. The complicated CSS of the chain link "image" is messing significantly with the SVG (especially stuff like the 90-degree rotation).  If the link and chain were both SVG this would be very straightforward. (NOTE: correction to SVG element above -- when using symbol, several of the attributes go in symbol instead of svg.)

Comment: well the OP provided a 90% solution using CSS and he wanted to add 10% of SVG, so in this case i guess better continue the 10% using CSS. And it's good IN THIS PARTICULAR case. Now if we talk in general, of course SVG is created to make our life easier to create different shapes and no one can say that's wrong, So why not adding a working answer where you show your pure SVG solution instead of simply saying that CSS is bad and the SVG is good :) ... also you may notice i improved his CSS code to remove a lot of unecessary things.

Comment: Also by doing this the OP will not only have the solution he will also learn new techniques such as linear gradient, radial gradient .. how to use multiple gradient. How to remove unecessary code and improve his markup using pseudo element, etc,etc

Comment: You’re right. I tried to update as much as I could *quickly*, but frankly it’s Saturday and I have a driveway to shovel. ;-) I’ll see if I can show off my crappy graphic design skillz a bit later. (You’ll note I undid the downvote on your response....)